# db2 9.5: substr function fails but left function works ok

Tags: performance, db2, substr, db2-luw

I have this select statement, but it never ends:

```
select * from table where substr(field,1,3)='001'
```

but when I change it to:

```
select * from table where left(field,3)='001'
```

it works! thus, I think it's a resources issue. Now, I'll have to modify the statement but I want to know if it's possible to solve this problem making changes to the db parameters, maybe from:

```
db2 get db cfg ...
```

**Aditional info:**

Version database is 9.5 (windows).

Field is one of 3 key fields of the table.

Table content: 863820 rows

Comment: Are you certain that this problem is reproducible?  It looks like it shouldn't even be happening to me.

Comment: It would help to know your version of DB2, but I suspect the optimizer: `SUBSTR` can force the system to ignore an index on `field`, because if the starting position is anything other than one, an index can't be used.  At all.  I thought that some of the more recent versions could detect the start-is-one condition, but that might be wrong.  `LEFT`, of course, works because the optimizer can guarantee that the query looks at the start of an indexed field.

Comment: I was wondering if it's posible to change a db parameter to allow more resources available to run the first statement

Comment: Use db2exfmt or Control-Centre or Data-Studio to compare the two access plans . Insufficient detail in your question. Is the 'field' the *first* column of an index?  When both queries run, have you compared the time spent waiting (for locks, for resources, for i/o etc)?  Have you attempted to tune the query with the index-advisor or similar tools?  It is foolish to tune unless you have diagnosed the problem first.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you ask "I was wondering if it's posible to change a db parameter to allow more resources available to run the first statement "

You could try `autoconfigure`  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008960.html

e.g.  `db2 autoconfigure using mem_percent 80 apply none`

to see what it would suggest (or change if you say `APPLY DB AND DBM` and not `APPLY NONE`) if you asked Db2 to use 80% of your system memory